# How to send requests to http ... to https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have deployed my ruby on rails app to heroku, bought my SSL certificate and set up `https` for my website via a third party provider.

Currently, all requests to `https://www.abc[dot]com` is ok, and also `abc[dot]com` is redirected to `https://www.abc[dot]com`.

However -

1) `https://abc[dot]com` results in

> 'Site can't be reached'

on my chrome browser
2) `http://abc[dot]com` results in

> This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.

How can I make both urls above redirect to `https://www.abc[dot]com`?

I have gone through the tutorial on [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl), but unable to resolve this yet.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS issue upstream of Heroku. Because Heroku doesn't expose IP addresses, you need to use a DNS host that supports ANAME records, or supports collapsed CNAME records at the root.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain

My DNS registrar didn't support this, so I ended up switching the DNS management to CouldFlare, for free. This made it all work flawlessly.